# Return image in HTTP response

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

After compute the scatter plot with

```
plt.scatter(...)
```

I can preview the graph with

```
plt.show()
```

However, I wish to save the plot with some sort of function like savefig() which store the image in a variable instead of a file, then return the variable in http response as content/png in django web framework

Comment: What is the format of the output for `plt.show()`?

Comment: @MiniGunnR It actually show the plot in a new window.

Comment: @MiniGunnR `plt.show()` will be rendered using `qt` I guess.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/wilsaj/862153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further searching, I found [Returning MatPotLib image as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108881/returning-matpotlib-image-as-string?rq=1)

This solution solved my problem. Thank you everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can return the plot as a png image like this:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from django.http import HttpResponse

def graph(request):
    fig = Figure()

    # draw your plot here ......
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    # .............

    canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type = 'image/png')
    canvas.print_png(response)
    return response
```

But, since matplotlib 2.2.0 print_png function doesn't take HttpResponse anymore.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
plt.savefig(save_file)
```

read more at: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `mpld3` that is designed for that, [here's a guide](https://mpld3.github.io/quickstart.html)

Specifically, have a look at `mpld3.fig_to_html()`