# PHP exec or AJAX problems with python matplot

Tags: php, python, ajax, matplotlib

, Hi guys I want AJAX to call a python script or PHP, any is fine... the problem is when I import `matplotlib.pyplot as plt` in python
as soon as I do that, the script dies and when I comment .pyplot it works fine, how can I solve this??

PHP

```
shell_exec('python ../cgi-bin/file.py 5 01/01/2017 02/05/2017');
```

AJAX

```
var id = 5;
var from = '01/01/2017';
var to = '02/05/2017';
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../cgi-bin/file.py',
    data: {id:id, from:from, to:to},
    success: function(response){
      output = response;
      alert(output);
    }
  });
```

The point of using python is to call data from a database and plot the values, then show it in the website. I heard something about using shell and giving root permission or something, but I'm lost. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated!.

Comment: Do you have access to the error that is raised when the script "dies"? If the problem is that the server is not able to produce any graphical output, you could try using a non-interactive backend, `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("Agg"); import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; #rest of code`.

Comment: I added your line, and the errors.log is no printing any more errors, cool... but the problem now is that the script is not plotting... by the way what is Agg? and what if I want to use another lib and have the same error, whats the trick?

Comment: You don't show the script that should plot anything, so one cannot know the problem. "Agg" is the backend which can be used to save plots as e.g. png images.

Comment: Possibly [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45162020/return-image-in-http-response) can be of help.