# How do I reference a matplotlib plot returned from a view in an html template in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, matplotlib

I am trying to interactively display plots from matplotlib in django. From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108881/returning-matplotlib-image-as-string), I see that I can send the plot from a view with this code:

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype="image/png")
# create your image as usual, e.g. pylab.plot(...)
pylab.savefig(response, format="png")
return response
```

So the view sends the plot as an `Httpresponse`, but how do I reference that in the html code of the template? I'm guessing it will be something like this but am having a tough time finding examples of html code:

```
<img src={ some reference to the plot here }>
```

Again, I think I can generate the plot with a view but am not sure how to reference that output in the html template.

Comment: You've missed the point. The src needs to point to the URL that serves the view.

Comment: So... In that view, if I set `template_name = "app/plot.html"` then the src for the plot will be that path? I'll try that. Thanks for help.

Comment: No, that's not what I said at all. See my answer for more explanation.

Comment: Oh... the URL that I have set in urls.py in `urlpatterns` with `path()`

Comment: I get it now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view is served by a URL. This view exists purely to serve the content of an image, therefore you should simply use its URL as the src in your img tag. For instance:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('path/to/my/image', views.my_image, 'my_image')
]
```

...

```
def my_image(request, ...):
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype="image/png")
    # create your image as usual, e.g. pylab.plot(...)
    pylab.savefig(response, format="png")
    return response
```

...

```
<img src="{% url "my_image" %}">
```